# Querybuilder with spring data elastic search

Tags: json, angularjs, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring data elasticsearch with angularjs,Now I get the following json data by angular querybuilder and pass it to spring controller

```
 {
 "bool": {
 "must": [
 {
  "term": {
  "name": "someone"
 }
 },
{
"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "term": {
        "status": "active"
       }
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

How to convert this json to use it for searching by spring data elastic search?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query dsl java api elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720464/query-dsl-java-api-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NativeSearchQueryBuilder`. [Click here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.misc.filter) for more info.

or you can use `@Query` in ElasticSearchRepository.